# To form, different roots

Tags: words, grammar-dikduk, commentaries, language

Are the roots צור (to form, shape, fashion) יצר (to create) and צר (to shape, form, model)  related or do they just share similar meanings?

Are there any commentaries, scriptures, that connect these roots?

Comment: צור and צר  definitely are, as the vav can often be omitted from the middle of a root. יצר most likely is as well. In general, when you have words with similar form and similar meaning, they're related.

Comment: How do you know these roots have these meanings? I've never heard of a root צר meaning that, or, I think, צור.

Comment: @ double AA: Found it in Hirsch his dictionary. P.s. See also doitinhebrew.com dictionary

Comment: צר is not a root - all biblical Hebrew roots are three letters

Comment: @JoshuaPearl צר may not be a root but could be seem as a parent root or structure to create different root words. But what I was trying to show is that I found these certain letter combinations with certain meanings when transfered to different words which seemed comparable. I also read about the common denomitor between them having to do with 'pressing' and also 'forming'. Which made me wonder...

Comment: ... if I could devine the Yetzrim as forces (certain inclinations, tendencies, urges, impulses, propensities, dispositions, predispositions etc) within man which 'form' and 'press' upon (or in) us the thoughts, emotions, feelings etc which lead to deads and actions (of) which (could lead to that what) is Tov or that what is Rah (as outcomes)?